# Text view if statement not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

Can anyone help me work out where I'm going wrong here. On the button click the media player plays one of the mfiles at random and I'm trying to set a textview depending on which file was played. Currently the setText if statements only match the audio playing half the time. Really not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
private final int SOUND_CLIPS = 3;
private int mfile[] = new int[SOUND_CLIPS];
private Random rnd = new Random();

MediaPlayer mpButtonOne;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mfile[0] = R.raw.one;  
    mfile[1] = R.raw.two;  
    mfile[2] = R.raw.three; 

    //Button setup
    Button bOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final TextView textOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)]);
             if (mpButtonOne==null){
                    //display a Toast message here

                    return;
             }


             mpButtonOne.start();
             if (mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)] == mfile[0]){
                 textOne.setText("one");
             }
             if (mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)] == mfile[1]){
                 textOne.setText("two");
             }               
             if (mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)] == mfile[2]){
                 textOne.setText("three");
             }
                mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new soundListener1());
                {
                }
```

So just to clarify the problem I am having is that the setText only matches the audio occasionally, not on every click. The rest of the time it displays the wrong text for the wrong audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are choosing another random file

```
mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)]
```

set that to a variable in `onClick()` then check against that variable in your `if` statement

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    int song = mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)];
    final TextView textOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, song);


    if (song == mfile[0]){
        textOne.setText("one");
    }
```

**Edit**

To make it a member variable so you can use it anywhere in the class, just declare it outside of a method. Usually do this before `onCreate()` just so all member variables are in the same place and it makes your code more readable/manageable.

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity
{
    int song;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        // your code
    }
```

then you can just initialize it in your `onClick()`

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

     song = mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)];
     final TextView textOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, song);
```

Comment: That helped me sort out the problem thanks a lot. Something else I wanted to do was to use the int song in a different onClick however the variable has to be local to that original onClick, how can I make a public one that I can use anywhere not just within the original onClick.

Comment: You need to declare it as a member variable so it has class scope instead of just local scope. I have edited with an example. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't really think that through, what I'm trying to do is get a replay button so it get's the song just played and onClick plays that same one again. Setting it as an int song; and initializing it just creates another random song to play. How would I go about some how returning the value of song once it's played so that I can play it again with a different onClick. Thank you for your help so far by the way.

Comment: Instead of making your `song` variable a member variable, keep it how it is and create another one, maybe called `curSong`, as a member variable and in your first `onClick()` you assign `curSong` to `song`. You're welcome